# Convert two string to the same byte length

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I have 2 strings in my PHP code, 1 is a parameter to my method and 1 is a string from an ini file.
The problem is that they are not equal, although they have the same content, probably due to encoding issues. When using var_dump, it is reported that the first string's lenght is 23 and the second string's length is 47 (see the end of my question for the reason behind this)

How can i make sure they are both encoded the same way and have the same length in the end so comparison won't fail? Preferably, i would like them to be utf8 encoded.

For reference, this is an excerpt from the code:

```
static function getString($keyword,$file) {

$lang_handle = parse_ini_file($file, true);

var_dump($keyword);
    foreach ($lang_handle as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($key);
        if ($key == $keyword) {
            foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
                var_dump("\t" . $subkey . " => " . $subvalue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following ini:

```
[clientcockpit/login.php]
header = "Kunden Login"
username = "Benutzername"
password = "Passwort"
forgot = "Passwort vergessen"
login = "Login"
```

When calling the method with getString("clientcockpit/login.php", "inifile.ini") the output is:

```
string 'clientcockpit/login.php' (length=23)
string '�c�l�i�e�n�t�c�o�c�k�p�i�t�/�l�o�g�i�n�.�p�h�p�' (length=47)
```

Comment: Does the problematic string come from the user or the ini file?

Comment: If i recall parse_ini_file() function has a bug with utf8 encode (multibytes). You'll probably need to change the encode of the .ini file. (i couldn't google the ref. for this info)

Comment: google it: php multibyte parse_ini_file
I think you'll find a clue for this problem. I'm not sure unfortunately.

Comment: @C. Ross the problematic string comes from the ini file
@Ismael I can't find any problems with parse_ini_file and php 5.2.6 (which I use), do you have a link? And perhaps an alternative to parse_ini_file which works?

Comment: @Pascal I don't know any alternative unfortunately. I still believe the problem is only with some encode. Save both .ini file and .php script (which call function parse_ini_file) with same encode. If it doesn't work, I don't know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your INI file seems to be in UTF16 encoding or similar, using two bytes to represent a single character. I guess that the strange characters in your string are actually NULL bytes (`\0`).

PHP's Unicode support is quite poor and I guess that `parse_ini_file()` does not support multibyte encodings properly. It will treat the file as if it was encoded using a "ASCII-compatible" single-byte encoding, just looking for special characters `[` and `]` to detect sections. As a result, the section keys will be corrupted: One byte actually belonging to `[` or `]` will be part of the section key:

```
UTF-16:    [c]    (3 characters, 6 bytes)

For UTF-16BE (big endian):

  Bytes:    00 5B    00 63    00 5D    (6 bytes)
  ASCII:    \0  [    \0  c    \0  ]    (6 characters)

For UTF-16LE (little endian):

  Bytes:    5B 00    63 00    5D 00    (6 bytes)
  ASCII:    [  \0    c  \0    ]  \0    (6 characters)
```

Assuming ASCII, instead of reading `c`, `parse_ini_file()` will read `\0c\0` if the source file encoding is UTF-16.

If you can control the format of your INI file, make sure to save it in UTF8 or ISO-8859-1 encoding, using your favorite text editor.

Otherwise you will have to read in the file contents using `file_get_contents()`, do the encoding conversion (eg. using `iconv()`) and pass the result to `parse_ini_string()`. The drawback here is that you will have to detect or hardcode the original file encoding.

If the `mb` multibyte extension is available on your PHP installation, you can use `mb_detect_encoding()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` to do the conversion dynamically.

Comment: Making absolutely sure that the file as saved as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 (in which the client supplied it), it seemed to work. I was unable to programmaticly convert the strings to other encodings using mbstrings however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lang_handle = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents($file), true);
```